# Accessing $_POST data sent by Jquery/AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am using this function:

```
function end_incident() {
    var dataString = 'name=Daniel&phone=01234123456';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.example.co.uk/erc/end_incident.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(msg){ 
            alert('Success!'+dataString);
        }
    });
};
```

to send information to `end_incident.php`, but I'm not able to access the `$_POST` variables. I've tried doing it like this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I hope [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is not an issue here.

Comment: @Salman A, that's what I am suspecting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try sending the data as an object:

```
function end_incident() {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://www.example.co.uk/erc/end_incident.php",
       data: { name: "Daniel", phone: "01234123456" },
       success: function(msg){ 
            alert('Success!');
       }
    });
};
```

Comment: Damn, wanted to post the same thing! You were faster :) +1

Comment: No, this won't make any difference. The `data` attribute can be set either as an object (in this case it will be converted to a query string) or as a string in the query string format. [See here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#sending-data-to-server).

Comment: Hi Richard D thanks for your reply. I think the problem was that I missed a couple of apostrophies in my SQL query and its now working but I like the layout you've used better anyway so I'll use that :)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the url your requesting for is **within the same origin** of your site, if it isn't, you've got a cross-site scripting issue. Only way around that:

- Getting "higher" access/priveledges within the browser, i.e. create an add-on/extension, or use Greasemonkey
- Use a proxy through your own site to get the request for the file:

  ```
  var getURL = "http://www.example.co.uk/erc/end_incident.php";
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/get_url.php?url=" + encodeURIComponent(getURL),
     data: { name: "Daniel", phone: "01234123456" },
     success: function(msg){ 
         alert('Success!');
     }
  });
  ```

I recommend you add a `error` function to your ajax. It's suprising how many people just focus on `success` and never process an error!

```
error: function()
{
   console.log(arguments);
}
```

Comment: +1 for error comment. But wouldn't it be a good idea to actually tell the user that an error occurred? You never know when your server or the user's WIFI might be down. `alert("Could not connect to the server. Please check your network connection or try again later.");` ...or something cleaner.